# adding tests to ionic v3 prior to v4 upddate

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I have a (complicated, live, in production) ionic app that is currently on ionic-angular 3.9.2 but has been around since (I think) the v1 days.  There are no tests (yikes).

I see that Ionic 4 ships with some e2e testing support which is great, but does me little good since it's not compatible with the version that I'm on.

I'd like to get some e2e tests in place prior to biting the bullet and migrating up to v4 and all the many changes that will entail.

Are there any resources available that can help me add tests to a v3 app in a way that will be compatible with v4 as I go through the update process?

Comment: why not migrate first then add tests? migration is not trivial in fact. i am 80% through with it and where i stand i would migrate first then add tests

Comment: because that’s backwards?

Comment: i think yes chances are you might have to do more of your code changes as part of migration. Writing tests now will increase code base for migration potentially